# Easier way to filter search for active or mature PyPI packages with pip or other tool?

Tags: python, pip, pypi, package-managers, yolk

[PyPI](https://pypi.org/) often has so many packages matching a given keyword, that it can be difficult to sort through the riffraff for the one you actually want. For example, `pip search kalman` returns 13 results, of which most (10 or 11) look promising by the description. Since each one could take hours to evaluate (digging into the docs, writing and timing test code etc.), the list has to be narrowed down a bit. *Sometimes* the version number at least gives a hint as to the maturity of the project, but that's it. The next step for me, is usually to manually look up each package one by one to get a better idea of it's maturity, community support, quality of documentation, and see if it's been updated recently. Usually the most up to date mature packages are a good place to start.

I came across [yolk](https://pypi.org/project/yolk/), which allows you to get a little more information about a package, but still no way to get last update date (that I could figure out, anyway).

**tldr;** I would something like a pip search that, along with version number, also lists some useful stats such as project age, last update date, number of downloads, or git commits, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try using Libraries.io for search instead, for example:

https://libraries.io/search?languages=Python&q=kalman

There's also a [`pypi-cli`](https://pypi.org/project/pypi-cli/) project which will give you some of the stats you're looking for:

```
$ pypi info matplotlib
matplotlib
==========
Python plotting package

Latest release:   1.3.1

Last day:           2,015
Last week:         16,744
Last month:        59,989

Author:   John D. Hunter, Michael Droettboom
Author email: mdroe@stsci.edu

PyPI URL:  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib
Home Page: http://matplotlib.org

License: BSD
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about libraries.io. Should do the trick. `pypi-cli` also looks great.